Use WS2811 as shift register
Has anyone used a WS2811 LED driver as a 3 bit shift register?
It's an IC for connecting ordinary LEDs to make them addressable with same protocol as the popular WS2812b LEDs. I just realized I can use it to transfer slow simple data over medium long distances.
For clarification, I know this IC is not a shift register. My plan is to use the PWM output 0 and 255 as logical 0 and 1 output.
@Kartman, you are right with stability issues for these chips. Forgot about that. For lights its not always noticeable, but for data it might be a problem.
Compared to a normal shift register, it only needs one pin instead of 2 or 3 pins.
I can also put WS2812b-LED son the same chain if I want a light down the line.
I guess I might need to put a smoothing capacitor on the PWM output to keep it at a steady 1 or 0.
Not sure if I will get problem with voltage level for 3v3 since the chip itself need minimum 3.5 V.
The "logic high" is specified as min 0.55 VDD, so probably it works with 3.3 V logic if I supply the chip with 5 V. However, the logic input is also specified as VDD-0.7, so not sure what is most important to follow.
The output is a sink type, so I think it should work with pulling 3.3 V logic low. It just gets inverted.

But it's not a 3 bit shift register inside, it's 24 bits.

that is the internal register for the 3 x 8bit pwm.
I am interested in digital on/off or IO data on the 3 output pins. This would be pwm duty cycle of 0 or 255 to give a 0 or 1 on the output.

So you shift in 24 bits at whatever speed the WS2811 requires, and 3 "analog" bits come out? What purpose does this serve?

I’m pretty sure it will work as you want. Note it is not a reliable protocol and the reason it works over distances is that each chip/led regenerates the digital signal. I’d be thinking wireless might be a better option - depends on your application.

Do you mean using it as a repeater, to boost your signal at intermediate points along a long cable or something? (Please edit your question and explain this, don't post this new info in comments.)
